# Knockout Object Binding

Tags: javascript, binding, knockout.js, mapping

Doing an GET, returning an object.  Wondering what the proper way to bind this:

```
var self = this;
$.getJSON("/api/contentsummary",
                        function (data) {
                            self.contentSummary =data.contentSummary;

                        });
```

To get this to function properly, I need to bind after every assignment.  What's the proper way to do this when the GET function is returning an object?

Comment: Do you mean that you need to call ko.applyBindings each time you make the assignment?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [**Knockout mapping** plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#example_using_komapping):

```
var self = this;

$.getJSON("/api/contentsummary", function (data) {
    self.contentSummary = ko.mapping.fromJS(data.contentSummary);
});
```

Comment: Okay, done: self.contentSummary.Count() is accessible from the console.  How does do I access the object in the view, not getting any data:


`<label for="Count">Count: <span data-bind="text: contentSummary.Count"></span></label>`

Comment: I guess the better question, do bindings need to be applied after every mapping.fromJS?

Comment: @user1959772 - Yes. Check the documentation (the link is in the answer). To update your model with new data, use this: `ko.mapping.fromJS(data.contentSummary, self.contentSummary);`

Comment: Missing something:
`self.Statuses = ko.observableArray();`
`$.getJSON("/api/Statuses", 
  function (data) {
   self.Statuses = ko.mapping.fromJS(data.Statuses);
   ko.applyBindings(self);
                        });
 }`
`<div id="ViewDirectories" data-bind="foreach: Status">
 <span data-bind="text: Suffix"></span>
</div>`

Comment: Wondering how to accomplish the following:
http://jsfiddle.net/atwoodkevin/q8EKP/