# how to make sure ajax fills knockout observable array before binding

Tags: ajax, mvvm, knockout.js

I am using jqwidgets grid and the example on their site to bind using ko observableArray.  However I think that the reason the grid is not showing data is because it is trying to bind before the ajax request is complete.  Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/delebash/KUhRG/6/) of my code. Also any resources on how to debug ajax using firebug, I know how to debug js code but when using ajax if I put a debugger; in the

```
.done(function (data) {
debugger;
                    var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);
                    me.items(jsonData);
                });
```

It doesn't fire if I have other debugger; statements outside of that function and I don't understand why.  I guess I don't fully understand the flow of async requests in javascript code.  Thanks again

Dan

Comment: possible duplicate of [Knockout Object Binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226477/knockout-object-binding)

Comment: @Joseph Silber, I actually have seen the mapping plugin, it looks useful, but I don't think that is the problem I am having from what I can tell.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is such sample available here: [gridwithjson.htm](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxknockout/gridwithjson.htm?classic)

Comment: That is the exact example I am using in the fiddle I posted but as you can see it is not loading any data.  I think this is because the ajax request is not completing but not sure.